# Change properties of button of other application?

Tags: winapi

i used api functions:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "Tested");//rename caption
EnableWindow(hWnd, false);//disable
```

but not working in .NET apps.

SendMessage function return true and i check caption of button is renamed (i used spy++ to check). But button's caption in the form not be changed. This problem is only happen with controls of .NET, With Delphi's controls its ok, no problem. I think to change controls's properties of .NET, have to use class of Accessibility. I used AccessibleObjectFromWindow api function to get state of .NET's controls but i don't know how to set state these controls, please tell me.

Comment: You'll need to be more descriptive. How is it not working? What is the return value from SendMessage?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work for Win32 `BUTTON` controls, but not all buttons are implemented that way. Some frameworks don't use the Win32 `BUTTON` control and that is the scenario you have encountered.

The issue you face is a consequence of you choosing the wrong technique for automation. You should use the platform automation framework, UI Automation.